# Why is the modal form in this bootstrap / impress.js Qt web application not showing?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, qt, qtwebkit, impress.js

I am trying to make a Qt web application using bootstrap and impress.js.

I used the bootstrap.css I found here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dTdEky6N to work with impress.js.

The problem is that while it seems the other bootstrap components show correctly, I cannot get the modal form to show at all. Nothing happens when I click "Open Modal". I also tried viewing the page in Firefox, but the modal form still will not show at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please be patient if I have not supplied everything needed to analyse the problem.

```
<link href="css/impress-demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

....

<div class="step slide bootstrapslide" data-x="1000" data-y="-1500">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn">Left</button>
      <button class="btn">Middle</button>
      <button class="btn">Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <button class="btn">Left</button>
      <button class="btn">Middle</button>
      <button class="btn">Right</button>
    </div>

    <p><span class="label label-success">Success</span></p>
    <p><span class="label label-warning">Warning</span></p>
    <p><span class="label label-danger">Danger</span></p>
    <p><span class="label label-info">Info</span></p>


    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

</div>

...

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/impress.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>impress().init();</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update: I have found the answer. It seems that bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css were not from the same version. Having fixed that, the modal form now displays correctly